# Positioning of turtles

Tags: netlogo

[Fishes and planktons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WIDU.jpg)

Hello! This is a 20x20 worls. Currently my program randomizes these planktons (green grass) and these fishes (orange fish). What I would like to do is to place all the planktons in just a certain portion of the world, say the lower left part, what should be my setxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you'd do something like:

```
move-to one-of patches with [pxcor < x and pycor < y]
```

And you do your geometry in that expression.

You can do similar with

```
setxy (random x) (random y)
```

and you make your own bounds.

Hope this helps.